# How to store JSON in javascript using hashmap

Tags: javascript, html, json, hashmap, frontend

**I have used the shrtcode api and I dont know how to store its data.**

```
var requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
redirect: 'follow'
};
fetch("https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=www.google.com", requestOptions)//api
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
 }
 Response
 ok true
 result 
 code             "fQdPc"
 short_link       "shrtco.de/fQdPc"
 full_short_link      "https://shrtco.de/fQdPc"
 short_link2          "9qr.de/fQdPc"
 full_short_link2  "https://9qr.de/fQdPc"
 short_link3          "shiny.link/fQdPc"
 full_short_link3  "https://shiny.link/fQdPc"
 share_link       "shrtco.de/share/fQdPc"
 full_share_link      "https://shrtco.de/share/fQdPc"
 original_link    "http://www.google.com"
```

**How can I print or store the value of "full_short_link   "?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const doStuff = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=www.google.com');
        const json = await res.json();

        console.log('full_short_link', json.result.full_short_link);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

doStuff();
```